# Connecting Mist to a remote private network. Duplicate or not?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

The question [How to connect Mist to a remote private network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/how-to-connect-mist-to-a-remote-privatenet) was marked as a duplicate of [Can Mist be attached to a Geth node on a different computer over HTTP RPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/can-mist-be-attached-to-a-geth-node-on-a-different-computer-over-http-rpc) .

The (1) first [duplicate] question is asking about how to connect Mist to a remote private network.

The (2) second question is asking whether it is possible to connect Mist to a remote `geth` node using HTTP RPC.

The answer to the (1) first question is that to connect Mist to a remote private network, spin up an instance of `geth` on your local computer and connect this `geth` instance to the remote network. Mist can then communicate with the local `geth` instance that will have the connection to the remote network. This is a workaround and not a direct connection from Mist to the remote private network, but it should work.

The answer to the (2) second question is No. It is not possible to connect Mist to a remote `geth` node using HTTP RPC.

I'm not fussed whether the first question is marked as a duplicate or not, but just would like to bring it to your attention that the questions and answers are slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a separate question but maybe there are benefits of seeing it as part of this "thread".  I will repost separately if desired.  We have 3 similar Questions:

Q1. [How to connect Mist to a remote private network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/how-to-connect-mist-to-a-remote-privatenet)

Q2. [Can Mist be attached to a Geth node on a different computer over HTTP RPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/can-mist-be-attached-to-a-geth-node-on-a-different-computer-over-http-rpc)

Q3. [How can I configure Mist to use a non-default IPC path?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/410/how-can-i-configure-mist-to-use-a-non-default-ipc-path)

Q1 was asked most recently.  If answerer knows that there are existing answers Q2 and Q3 that answer part of Q1, could/should answerer edit Q1 to focus on what Q2 and Q3 didn't cover?  (This assumes Q1 can be edited in such a way.  If questioner wants to know about the part of the question that was removed, they could search and maybe find Q2/Q3.)

Or do we edit parts of Q1's answer to link to Q2/Q3?  This could mean removing a "big chunk" of Q1's answer though (and personally I try to avoid big edits of other people's stuff).

Or something else?

As the site grows, this pattern of related questions and "almost-dupes" will appear to increase.

EDIT: For example, new one that popped up...

[How can I force geth to create accounts in a different keystore?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/how-can-i-force-geth-to-create-accounts-in-a-different-keystore)

[Possible to store the blockchain in a different directory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1724/)

Comment: We need some FAQs sticked or sidebar-red with a link to these common questions.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) How to connect Mist to a remote privatenet?

I don't see how this differs from:

> (2) Can Mist be attached to a Geth node on a different computer over HTTP RPC?

Except that (2) knows there is no way to use IPC over remote and therefore already included a suggestion for RPC.

I see that for (1) the 'workaround' would be connecting to a local node which connects to ... a remote network! ;-)

I don't see the difference in connecting to a 'different computer' and a 'remote network'. And by the way, you can always cast reopen votes and the community will decide if it's a duplicate or not (5 votes to reopen).

Comment: I've voted to reopen and will let anyone else decide. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I thought I saw a similar answer too (excluding last part) and found it... http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/410/how-can-i-configure-mist-to-use-a-non-default-ipc-path  Maybe a merge might also help community...  (moderating is not easy :|)

Comment: I agree that moderating is not easy. Thank you for doing so. A merge would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that all the questions are same, but it phrased differently and asking for specific answers.

This all will help future visitors through search or something, it could be better if we merge or connect them one another.

Possibly disable answers if any question have a satisfying answer.